# PECL - Error not found installing extension

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl

I want to install `cld` exention with pecl. There is a strange error and I don't know how to solve it. Following the log: http://pastebin.com/YunLWetm, how to solve it? My SO is Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Log says it is unable to find libcld. This extension requires you to have it installed and avilable in your system path

Comment: Where can i find the official .deb?